# python argparse default with nargs wont work

Tags: python, argparse, default

Here is my code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, RawTextHelpFormatter 

example_text = "test"

parser = ArgumentParser(description='my script.',
                        epilog=example_text,
                        formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('host', type=str, default="10.10.10.10",
                    help="Device IP address or Hostname.")
parser.add_argument('-j','--json_output', type=str, default="s", nargs='?',choices=["s", "l"],
                    help="Print GET statement in json form.")
#mutally exclusive required settings supplying the key
settingsgroup = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
settingsgroup.add_argument('-k', '--key', type=str, 
                    help="the api-key to use. WARNING take care when using this, the key specified will be in the user's history.")
settingsgroup.add_argument('--config', type=str, 
                    help="yaml config file. All parameters can be placed in the yaml file. Parameters provided from form command line will take priority.")

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.json_output)
```

my output:

```
None
```

Everything I am reading online says this should work, but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: I believe you actually want a flag (`add_argument('-j', '--json_output', action='store_true')`)

Comment: I dont, I want to be able to pass either `s` or `l` to the argument. but if the user only passes '-j` with no value, use `s` by default.

Comment: If you don't run the command with `-j` it will work as expected and use `s` by default. Maybe you could check if the `-j` is `None` and set it to `s` then

Comment: Ah that is a misconception of mine then. Is there a way to make -j use `s` if -j is passed with no parameter?

Comment: CLI design wise it doesn't make sense to make an argument like the one in your code. Maybe what you should do instead is add an `--output-type` with `choices=['json-s', 'json-l', 'normal']` and set the default to `'normal'`

Comment: what's your command line?  I also recommend including a debugging `print(args)`

Comment: To make full use of `nargs='?'` you need to specify a `const`.  That should be documented.  `parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const='c', default='d')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `const=` parameter. `const` stores its value when the option is present but have no values

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-j', '--json-output', nargs='?', choices=['s', 'l'], const='s')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

However design wise, it might be better to use the following:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-o', '--output-type', choices=['json-s', 'json-l', 'normal'], default='normal')

args = parser.parse_args()
```